# How to calculate the total span of an object?

Tags: variables, language-agnostic, scope, metrics

What is the total span of variable `s` in the code below?

```
1: procedure sum(array: integer_array)
2:     var s: integer;
3: begin
4:     s := 0;
5:     for i in array'range loop
6:         s := s + array(i);
7:     end loop;
8: end;
```

The way I see it there are two possible interpretations:

1. The declaration in line 1 does *not* count as a reference, and then *total_span(s)* = 1
2. The declaration in line 1 *does* count as a reference, and then *total_span(s)* = 3

Here are two common definitions to help clarify the question:

- A variable's **total span** is the number of lines of code between the first statement in which it’s referenced until the last statement in which it’s referenced. (This is what McConnell calls *live time* in Code Complete, with the minor difference that he uses inclusive limits and so *live time* = *total span* + 2)
- A variable's **average span** is the average number of lines of code between two consecutive references to the variable

Note that these concepts are not related with memory allocaction, scope, or where the variable *could* be used in the code. These are metrics that refer to the *actual* use of a variable in the code.

Answer (score 1):

My take on this is that the declaration does not count, but the initialization counts.

Using your example, the declaration on line 2 does not count, because the variable does not get initialized until line 4, meaning that it cannot be counted "live" until then.

In some cases, a declaration constitutes an implicit initialization (e.g. C++ declarations of objects with types that have a default constructor). In these cases the declaration and initialization happen on the same line, meaning that the line of the declaration should be considered the first use of the variable.

Comment: I was thinking about that, do you think it would be reasonable to say that the range starts where the variable gets initialized with a value that is relevant to the algorithm? In the language I work with, variable `s` would get a default value of -INF on line 2, but the initialization that is really relevant to the algorithm is the one in line 4.

Comment: @rick If the language gives you no choice to declare the variable at the point of its first assignment (i.e. line 4) then I agree with you that it is reasonable to disregard the fact that `s` has been initialized to `-INF`. If, however, the declaration and the first meaningful initialization are separated by choice (a common mistake among experienced C-to-Java converts, when all variables are declared at the top of a function) then the span should start at the initialization, because the metric is supposed to encourage shorter spans.

Answer (score 0):

Just answering the question here, Maybe this would be helpful: The Span of 's' here is 2 and Average Span is 2 as well.