# Do same-line references of a variable contribute to its span?

Tags: javascript, variables, metrics

I have a question about the variable "span" metric.

I'm planning on writing a program in JavaScript that parses some JS and returns the span or live time of a variable. I learned about those two metrics after reading *Clean Code* by Steve McConnell. That means I've chosen to rely on [his definition](https://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/books/programming/code-complete-2-steve-mcconnell-general-issues-using-variables/) of them. (In that article, the relevant text is under the "Scope" header.)

Example:

```
let a = 3;
let b = 0;
b = 2;
a = 1;
```

So `a`'s span here would be `2`, and `b`'s span would be `0`.

I'm trying to understand whether if a variable is mentioned twice on the same line, **do I use the second reference on the same line in my calculation?** Or do I only increment by 1 for every 1+ references to a line?

I assume the point of factoring that into span is because it could represent that you're using too many references to the same variable on one line or something?

Example:

```
let a = 0;

a = a + a
```

So would that mean that the average span for the above example would be (1 + 0 + 0) / 3? The denominator would increase if I added the multiple references per line to my calculation so the number would definitely change.

McConnell [said that](https://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/books/programming/code-complete-2-steve-mcconnell-general-issues-using-variables/)

> "to [measure] how close together the references to a variable are," you check how many "lines come between the first reference to [it] and the second."

Sergey Kalinichenko [said that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26220633/16167096)

> "the declaration and initialization happen on the same line, meaning that the line of the declaration should be considered the first use of the variable."

However, I think he was talking about whether declaration counts as the start of live time.

Comment: If I'm understanding the concept correctly, the point of the metric is to keep the lines between references to a minimum, so I think it would be better in your example to count the average span as 1. Instead of `a = a + a + a + ...`, you could write `a *= n`. Should the metric heavily favor the first over the second?

Comment: Also, remember that it's just one metric and doesn't tell you with 100% accuracy that your code is "clean" or not.

Comment: Yeah, remembering things that keep the number of references on a line to a minimum could just satisfy me I guess. I might as well just only count one reference per line even so if something arises, since it's about LINES of code. Thanks for the input.